# Is there an error in the next task's condition?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2} \frac{(1-\sin(x))(\cos(x)^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)}{\cos(x)^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: By $\cos(x)^{2}$ do you mean $\cos^{2}(x) = (\cos x)^{2}$ or $\cos (x^{2})$?

Comment: if you mean $\cos(x)^{2} = (\cos x)^{2}$ then the above limit does not exist.

Comment: Have you tried using L'Hôpital's Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the answer is not correct in view of  $$series(((1-sin(x))*(cos(x)^2+1)-(1/2)*sin(2*x))/cos(x)^2, x = (1/2)*Pi, 3);$$ $$( \left( x-1/2\,\pi  \right) ^{-1}+{\frac {1}{2}}+O \left( x-1/2\,\pi 
 \right) ).
 $$ The right answer is undefined or infinity (This depends on your interpretation.).